# ASP.NET API: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I am trying to connect to a MySql database from my .Net Core API project.

This is my context class:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext() { }

    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options)
         : base(options) { }

    public MyContext(DbContextOptions options)
         : base(options) { }

        ...
}
```

and this is my *startup.cs*:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    string MyConnectionString = "server=localhost;port=3306;user=root;password=*****;database=my_db";
    services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => options.UseMySQL(MyConnectionString));
}
```

I know this question has already been asked a million times, but I still can't fix it.

*Edit:* In controllers, I instantiate my `MyContext` using the parameterless constructor.

Comment: try with this Server=.\\instanceName;Database=my_db;User Id=root;Password=********;

Comment: no port name required and write the instance name (sql server name) this should work, if that the case let me know so I can leave you an answer.

Comment: Try to put 'services.AddMvc()' as the last operation of your method.

Comment: Are you using .NET Core 2.1 ? Cause, if I undestand correctly, it is not supported : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core.html

Comment: @jirka .NET Core 2.0. And I also tried your previous suggestion, didn't help.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ Tried to remove the port name, didn't help...

Comment: Try to remove the default constructor of your dbcontext (public MyContext() { })

Comment: You need to inject your context into your controller, or repository, rather than instantiating it. Alternatively you can use a factory implementation to create your context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try something else :

First, in your DbContext create `OnConfiguring` method :

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder
           .UseMYSQL("... connection string ...");           
    }
```

Secondly, on the beginning of you `ConfigureServices` method, configure the DbContext this way :

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>();
```

Comment: That actually worked, thanks! Is there an explanation of why my code didn't work? Because I found it on Microsoft's website :-)

Comment: No idea.. I suppose the "dbcontext black box" called your parameter-less constructor. My way forces the configuration every time, not only on application start... Could you please mark the answer as accepted ? :)