# Can't read app settings in .NET Core API project

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, configurationmanager

I have a .NET Core API project and I am trying to read some settings from the *appsettings.json* file.

The file looks like this:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "Debug": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    }
  },
  "ConnectionString": "abc"
}
```

and I am trying to read the `ConnectionString` setting like this:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];
```

but I get `null`, and apparently no app settings have been detected at all.

**Edit:**

Here is what I have now:

*startup.cs*

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<MyContext>();
            services.AddMvc();
            services.Configure<ConnectionStringSettings>(Configuration);
        }
}
```

*ConnectionStringSettings.cs*

```
 public class ConnectionStringSettings
    {
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    }
```

*appsettings.json*

```
{
  "Logging": {
    ...
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Debug": "abc"
  }
}
```

*MyContext.cs*
public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        string x;

```
    public MyContext() { }

    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options)
        : base(options) { }

    public MyContext(IOptions<ConnectionStringSettings> connectionStringSettings)
    {
        x = connectionStringSettings.Value.ConnectionString;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
       //here I need my connection string
        optionsBuilder.UseMySql(connectionString);
    }
```

}

Comment: If I am not mistaken, `ConfigurationManager` is for use with the App.config files, and not the new appsettings.json files. You need to use the `ConfigurationBuilder` class as demonstrated in the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453495/how-to-read-appsettings-values-from-config-json-in-asp-net-core) with `IConfiguration`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your requirement of setting the connection string in the `OnConfiguring` override in your context, you can use the following approach.

Update your *appsettings.json* configuration file to contain a new JSON object for your database options

```
{
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Warning"
        }
    },
    "DatabaseOptions": {
        "ConnectionString": "<Connection String>"
    }
}
```

Create your model class which your *DatabaseOptions* configuration will map to

```
public class DatabaseOptions
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

Then update your `Startup` class' `ConfigureServices` method to register an instance of `IOptions<DatabaseOptions>`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.Configure<DatabaseOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("DatabaseOptions"));
}
```

And finally, update your context constructor to inject your `IOptions<DatabaseOptions>` instance, ASP.NET Core will handle the dependency injection for you as long as you register your context in the service collection.

```
public class MyContext
{
    private readonly DatabaseOptions databaseOptions;

    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options, IOptions<DatabaseOptions> databaseOptions)
        : base(options)
    {
        this.databaseOptions = databaseOptions.Value;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        //here I need my connection string
        optionsBuilder.UseMySql(databaseOptions.ConnectionString);
    }
}
```

Personally, I don't like naming classes with *Options* in the name when that class is going to be used with `IOptions<T>`, but as developers we can spend a large time of coding just thinking of class and variable names, feel free to rename as you please.

Comment: How should my *appsettings.json* look in this case?

Comment: I have written this answer around your current *appsettings.json* style. I would definitely recommend using the *ConnectionStrings* JSON property as you can then use the `GetConnectionString` method, and independently encrypt a section of that config file.

Comment: I have updated my answer to work with the *ConnectionStrings* property

Comment: I've edited my answer with what I've got now, but there are still some missing pieces. Please take a look.

Comment: The problem is that you're mixing both of my answers. If you're using *ConnectionStrings* then you shouldn't use `services.Configure`, instead just use `var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default");
    services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);`

Comment: My problem is that my `optionsBuilder.UseMySql(connectionString);` has to stay in the `OnConfiguring()` method, for some other reasons.

Comment: @Eutherpy, rewrote answer based on your requirements.

Comment: I did all this, but for some reason the parameterless constructor for `MyContext` (which I need) is called instead of the one with parameters, so my `databaseOptions` in `OnConfiguring()` is `null`.

Comment: Why do you need a parameterless constructor?

Comment: That's how I instantiate my context in the controllers.

Comment: What's wrong with `services.AddDbContext<MyContext>()`, and injecting your context?

Comment: For some reason that didn't work for me. See my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52295259/asp-net-api-no-database-provider-has-been-configured-for-this-dbcontext

Answer (score 3):

For .NET Core 2.x you need to set configuration up in startup as below

```
 public partial class Startup
    {
        public static IConfiguration Configuration;

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
    ...
}
```

Then access as below

```
Configuration.GetConnectionString("System")
```

You should also have your connection strings laid out as below.

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "System": "{connection String}"
  }
```

This will allow for multiple strings if required but work even if you only have the one.

EDIT: Once you've got the string, as ColinM says in his answer you need to register the string with a class which you can inject into your classes. In startup as below.

```
services.AddSingleton<IConnectionStringFactory, ConnectionStringFactory>(serviceProvider => new ConnectionStringFactory(Configuration.GetConnectionString("System")));
```

Your connection string class...

```
public class ConnectionStringFactory : IConnectionStringFactory
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public ConnectionStringFactory(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public string Invoke()
    {
        return _connectionString;
    }
}
```

Inject into your class as so...

```
public class ClassName
{
    private readonly IConnectionStringFactory _connectionStringFactory;

public ClassName(IConnectionStringFactory connectionStringFactory)
    {
        _connectionStringFactory = connectionStringFactory;
    }

...
}
```

Your interface can be as simple as below

```
public interface IConnectionStringFactory
{
}
```

You don't need to use an interface but I'd recommend this approach

Comment: @Eutherpy ColinM's answer goes into that more, you'll want register a DB context with the connection string as per his example. Then any class you need to access it with you can do so via Dependency Injection in the class's constructor. Have updated my answer to show you this with DI

Comment: I've edited my answer with what I've got now, but there are still some missing pieces. Please take a look.

Comment: @Eutherpy You can (and should) do this configuration in startup, for your  example this would look like this - services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("System")));

Replacing your "services.AddDbContext<MyContext>();" line in startup with the above should do the trick. MyContext should also inherit from DbContext - "MyContext : DbContext". If this doesn't work what's the error you're getting?

Comment: @Eutherpy have you gotten this working? If so can you mark the correct answer?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I went with another approach. +1

Answer (score 0):

You should use Configuration in Startup =>

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
       var section = Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionString");
       var value= Configuration.GetValue<string>("ConnectionString")
    }
```